# Combining StateT and ExceptT monad tranformers

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, state-monad

I have the following little working program:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-} 
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import Control.Monad.State.Strict
import Control.Monad.Except
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.Read as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T
main :: IO ()
main = do
    _ <- execStateT loop 0
    return ()

loop :: StateT Int IO ()
loop = do
    liftIO $ putStrLn "Enter a Number"
    line <- liftIO $ T.getLine
    let ts = T.words line
    checkFoo ts
    loop

checkFoo ::  (MonadState Int m, MonadIO m) => [T.Text] -> m()
checkFoo strs = liftIO (runExceptT
    (check1 strs >>= checkNum >>= doFoo)) >>= result
  where
    doFoo n = liftIO $ putStrLn $ "Your number: " <> show n

check1 :: [a] -> ExceptT T.Text IO a
check1 ts =
    if length ts == 1
        then return $ head ts
        else throwError "1 number please"

checkNum :: T.Text ->  ExceptT T.Text IO Int
checkNum t = case T.decimal t of
                Left _ -> throwError "input isn't a number"
                Right (d, _) -> return $ d

result :: (MonadState Int m, MonadIO m) => Either T.Text () -> m ()
result (Left e) = liftIO $ T.putStrLn e
result (Right _) = return ()
```

Now I would like to access the value of the State Monad in the subfunction `doFoo` of my function `checkFoo`. eg:

```
    doFoo n =
        old <- lift get
        let s = old + n
        liftIO $ putStrLn $ "The sum of your numbers: " <> show s
        lift $ put s
        pure ()
```

I get the following error:

```
Main.hs:26:35: error:
    • Could not deduce (MonadState a0 IO) arising from a use of ‘doFoo’
      from the context: (MonadState Int m, MonadIO m)
        bound by the type signature for:
                   checkFoo :: forall (m :: * -> *).
                               (MonadState Int m, MonadIO m) =>
                               [T.Text] -> m ()
        at Main.hs:24:1-60
      The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    • In the second argument of ‘(>>=)’, namely ‘doFoo’
      In the first argument of ‘runExceptT’, namely
        ‘(check1 strs >>= checkNum >>= doFoo)’
      In the first argument of ‘liftIO’, namely
        ‘(runExceptT (check1 strs >>= checkNum >>= doFoo))’
   |
26 |     (check1 strs >>= checkNum >>= doFoo)) >>= result
```

Why is this not working? What are the necessary changes to make this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you write the expression:

```
check1 strs >>= checkNum >>= doFoo
```

this requires that each of these operations is an action is the *same monad*.  The monad for the first two is:

```
ExceptT T.Text IO
```

which implies a type signature for `doFoo`:

```
doFoo :: Int -> ExceptT T.Text IO ()
```

but then you try to lift `put` and `get` operations in your revised `doFoo` definition.  The error message is telling you that these operations aren't supported by the stateless monad `ExceptT T.Text IO`.

The least disruptive fix is probably to modify the type signatures for `check1` and `checkNum` to generalize them over any `MonadIO m`:

```
check1 :: (MonadIO m) => [a] -> ExceptT T.Text m a
checkNum :: (MonadIO m) => T.Text ->  ExceptT T.Text m Int
```

Then, `checkFoo` can be written as follows, without the `liftIO` before `runExcept`.  I've also removed the `lift` before `get` and `put`.  They aren't necessary, as `get` and `put` automatically lift themselves to the closest containing `StateT` transformer.

```
checkFoo ::  (MonadState Int m, MonadIO m) => [T.Text] -> m ()
checkFoo strs = runExceptT (check1 strs >>= checkNum >>= doFoo) >>= result
  where
    -- doFoo :: (MonadState Int m, MonadIO m) => Int -> m ()
    doFoo n = do
        old <- get
        let s = old + n
        liftIO $ putStrLn $ "The sum of your numbers: " <> show s
        put s
        pure ()
```

This version runs the pipeline `check1 strs >>= checkNum >>= doFoo` in the monad `ExceptT T.Text m` where `m` is the same monad `(MonadState Int m, MonadIO m) => m` that appears in `checkFoo`'s type signature.  The result is passed to `result :: (MonadIO m) => Either T.Text () -> m ()` again for that same monad `m`.  In your code, `checkFoo` is called at `m ~ StateT Int IO`, which satisfies the constraints `MonadState Int m` and `MonadIO m`, so all is well with the type checker.

The full revised example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import Control.Monad.State.Strict
import Control.Monad.Except
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.Read as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T

main :: IO ()
main = do
    _ <- execStateT loop 0
    return ()

loop :: StateT Int IO ()
loop = do
    liftIO $ putStrLn "Enter a Number"
    line <- liftIO $ T.getLine
    let ts = T.words line
    checkFoo ts
    loop

checkFoo ::  (MonadState Int m, MonadIO m) => [T.Text] -> m ()
checkFoo strs = runExceptT (check1 strs >>= checkNum >>= doFoo) >>= result
  where
    -- doFoo :: (MonadState Int m, MonadIO m) => Int -> m ()
    doFoo n = do
        old <- get
        let s = old + n
        liftIO $ putStrLn $ "The sum of your numbers: " <> show s
        put s
        pure ()

check1 :: (MonadIO m) => [a] -> ExceptT T.Text m a
check1 ts =
    if length ts == 1
        then return $ head ts
        else throwError "1 number please"

checkNum :: (MonadIO m) => T.Text ->  ExceptT T.Text m Int
checkNum t = case T.decimal t of
                Left _ -> throwError "input isn't a number"
                Right (d, _) -> return $ d

result :: (MonadState Int m, MonadIO m) => Either T.Text () -> m ()
result (Left e) = liftIO $ T.putStrLn e
result (Right _) = return ()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here are the type annotations for `check1` and `checkNum`. They don't mention the `State Int` monad. They should be:

```
check1 :: [a] -> ExceptT T.Text (StateT Int IO) a
checkNum :: T.Text ->  ExceptT T.Text (StateT Int IO) Int
```

Then the code for `checkFoo` should be:

```
checkFoo strs = (runExceptT
    (check1 strs >>= checkNum >>= doFoo)) >>= result
```